# Programmatically clicking an <A> from unit test in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I have the following AngularJS directive working just fine:

```
angular.module('kerrb.components').directive('krbMinimalizeSidebar', krbMinimalizeSidebar);

function krbMinimalizeSidebar($timeout) {
return {
  // restricted to use as an attribute only
  restrict: 'A',
  template: '<a class="navbar-minimalize minimalize-styl-2 btn btn-primary "
              href="" ng-click="minimalize()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>',
  controller: ['$scope', '$element', function ($scope, $element) {
    $scope.minimalize = function () {
        // snipped for brevity
    };
  }]
};
}

krbMinimalizeSidebar.$inject = ['$timeout'];
```

The attribute is added to a SPAN tag. I have one unit test that is passing when it checks for the rendered `<A>` tag with the specific CSS class. However in another test I'm trying to programmatically click the `<A>` so I can see if the underlying `minimalize()` method is called. The problem is that whenever I call the click event, it says `undefined is not a function...`. I can confirm I have a reference to the `<A>` tag... just can't figure out why the `click` event isn't working as I'm doing things very similar to **[this working sample](https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing/blob/master/test/tabsSpec.js)**.

Here's what my test looks like:

```
it('should bind to the scope event', function () {
  var anchor = element.find('a');
  console.log(': ' + anchor.length);
  console.log(': ' + anchor[0].outerHTML);
  console.log(': ' + anchor[0].tagName);

  anchor[0].click();
});
```

And the output on the console:

```
': 1'
': <a class="navbar-minimalize minimalize-styl-2 btn btn-primary " href="" ng-click="minimalize()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>'
': A'

    TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'anchor[0].click()')
```

Everything appears correct... why wouldn't a click() work on a DOM element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular's implementation of element does not have a click() function. (See the [Angular.element documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).) Instead, you have two options:

1. **Include jQuery**. If jQuery is loaded, Angular's element object is automatically replaced with the jQuery implementation which does include a click() function. However, if your application doesn't already use jQuery for some other reason, this would be a non-optimal solution since it would test your application in a different configuration that you would deploy.
2. **Call `triggerHandler('click')` instead of `click()`**. The `triggerHandler` function calls all of the listeners to a specified event. In your case:

   `anchor[0].triggerHandler('click')`

   ...should call your ng-click handler.

Comment: Good call on jQuery... I wasn't using it but got that part working. The 'triggerHandler('')' is what I needed as even using jQuery didn't do it. Trying to get my stub working so now I can test if the function is being called. I added a Console.Log() to the function and can see it is being called, but my stub isn't catching it. I'll keep digging away...